# Regarding copying key value pairs of javascript objects

Tags: node.js

**I was trying to create a copy of error object sent by mongoose by doing let error = {...err}.
err was the original error object. Now when I logged to console(err.name) it shows "CastError" which is expected but (error.name) was giving "undefined" , but when I used error = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(err)) and then logged both err.name and error.name both are showing expected "CastError" output, my doubt is why {...err} didn't worked
[When using {...err}[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKoyr.png)
**

[When using JSON.parse()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihasO.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ahah, good question! To answer that, you need to carefully read the documentation and pay close attention to the little details:

1. The [spread syntax of object literals documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#spread_in_object_literals) mentions: *It copies own **enumerable** properties from a provided object onto a new object.*
2. The [ECMAScript documentation of Error objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-error-objects) indicates that all properties are **non enumerable**.

The result of those 2 specifications is that when you try to clone an Error object using the spread syntax, it results in an empty object. You can confirm this behavior using [`Object.prototype.propertyisEnumerable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/propertyIsEnumerable)

```js
const err = new Error()
console.log(err.propertyIsEnumerable('message')) // result: false
console.log(err.propertyIsEnumerable('name')) // result: false

const error = {...err}
console.log(err) // result: {}
```

If you absolutely need to list the non enumerable properties of an object, you can call [`Object.getOwnPropertyNames`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) which returns all the properties (enumerable and non enumerable) of the object itself. If needed, you can walk up the prototype chain with `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)` and repeat the operation. Note that you will probably want to filter out the properties coming from the Object prototype.

Here is a sample code (there are probably better ways to write this...):

```js
const getAllProps = (obj, props = []) => {
  props.push(...Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj));
  const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
  if (proto !== null) return getAllProps(proto, props);
  return props;
};
const objProps = getAllProps({});

const err = new Error();
const errProps = getAllProps(err).filter((prop) => !objProps.includes(prop));
console.log(errProps); // result: [ 'stack', 'name', 'message' ]
```